# text manipulation in django as soon as user/admin enters it

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms, text-processing

i have a simple model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    custom_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

custom function:
    def process_text(my_string):
        return len(my_string)

i want the following:

```
custom_name = process_text(name)
```

Suppose the admin enters `name` as `Mark Pilgrim` then `custom_name` should have the auto populated value of `12`.

in the admin.py can i have something like

```
prepopulated_fields
```

what would be an easy way to go about it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to add a method that listens on the `pre_save` signal.

Here is a sample you can use (this code goes in your `models.py` for the app)

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Your models go here   
def process_text(mystring):
    return len(mystring)

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Article)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    if not kwargs['raw']:
         obj = kwargs['instance']
         obj.custom_name = process_string(obj.name)
```

The [signals documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) has more information on signals, and the [`pre_save` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) lists what arguments the method expects.

Answer (score 0):

If you have form with those fields then you can use some javascript to update the second field when the first lost focus. Then when someone will enter something in to the first field and leave the field, js can calculate length and put the value in second field.

If this should be done in the backend level - then you can for example override model's save() method. More here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best option is to set the value on the form validation stage.

Comment: could you elaborate more on that?